# Why does print() print an empty tuple instead of a newline?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

**The error was caused by a typo. Please flag this question as off-topic.**

I am having a little issue with the following lines.

```
from __future__ import print_function
print()
```

If I open up my Windows CLI and run it, it runs as expected.

[image]

When I stick it in a program and execute it, instead of simply printing a newline, it prints `()`.

[image]

Has anybody run into this before?

**Additional Details:**

If I run a program with just those two lines, it runs as expected.

But for some reason, in my program `print()` prints `()`. If I replace that line with `print(1)`, it prints `1` as it should.

Running on Windows 8 64-bit. Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775)

**Minimal, complete, and verifiable example:**

```
class A:
    def f(self):
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.f()
```

**Final Update:**

Oh my!!!! I am an idiot.

I have a driver program that has the future import, but the class (which is another file) does not! I do have statements like `print('abc', file=sys.stderr)`, but they were not being executed, so the program ran no problem.

My example above actually runs fine. The example I was running didn't have the import. The file I was editing (otherwise an exact copy of the example) did.

Woops!!!!

Comment: It just prints a newline in my console. I don't get an empty tuple. I'm on a windows machine, if it makes a difference.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on python 2.7 and I'm on Windows as well. Incidentally, you don't need the constructor in this class, and it is a good habit to subclass from `object` (although it's not necessary for this particular class)

Comment: In Python 2.7.x `print()` returns a tuple but in python 3.5.x `print()` returns a newline. Have you checked your Python versions ?

Comment: Nope. Win7, i3, HP lappy - not seeing this behavior in either IDLE, CLI or PowerShell running a script or from command line input. FWIW, when I run your verifiable example without the __future__ import, as you'd expect, I do get a "()" printed...

Comment: Even with the import, that code just prints an empty line for me. Python 2.7.11, Arch Linux x64.

Comment: I don't see the behavior you describe in the interactive shell or in a saved script. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: My own stupid fault. There's no problem.

Comment: If the issue does not exist, your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was incorrect, and the behavior was caused by something else, you should probably delete this question.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Alright. I flagged it as off topic, but perhaps I'll just delete it. What is the right protocol. Will people lose rep if I delete?

Comment: Probably for the best, yeah. As it stands, it'll just confuse people trying to figure out `print`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Actually I can't, since there were answers posted. I guess I need to wait until it's closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) is a special statement in python2.

When you do :

```
from __future__ import print_function
print()
```

You are actually calling the [print function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), which has the same behavior as the one in python3.

In your program, you call the statement, and not the function. Hence, the `print()` prints an empty tuple (which is indeed what `()` is).

**Additional note :**

If I add `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of your example, I get a newline as expected, and not an empty tuple.

Answer (score 1):

In your second program `python myprog.py` you need to include the `from __future__ import print_function` line.